# Why dynamic component is not working in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Here is a working Vue2 example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>O_o</h1>
        <component :is="name"/>
        <button @click="onClick">Click me !</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            isShow: false
        }),
        computed: {
            name() {
                return this.isShow ? () => import('./DynamicComponent') : '';
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onClick() {
                this.isShow = true;
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Redone under Vue3 option does not work. No errors occur, but the component does not appear.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>O_o</h1>
        <component :is="state.name"/>
        <button @click="onClick">Click me !</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {ref, reactive, computed} from 'vue'

    export default {
        setup() {
            const state = reactive({
                name: computed(() => isShow ? import('./DynamicComponent.vue') : '')
            });

            const isShow = ref(false);

            const onClick = () => {
                isShow.value = true;
            }

            return {
                state,
                onClick
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Has anyone studied the vue2 beta version? Help me please. Sorry for the clumsy language, I use Google translator.

Comment: try it like this. `async () => await import('./DynamicComponent')`

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately, nothing has changed.

Comment: hi @progervova, any update on this? I am on the same situation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leave everything in the template as in Vue2

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>O_o</h1>
        <component :is="name"/>
        <button @click="onClick">Click me !</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Change only in "setup" using defineAsyncComponent

You can learn more about defineAsyncComponent here
https://labs.thisdot.co/blog/async-components-in-vue-3

```js
const isShow = ref(false);
const name = computed (() => isShow.value ? defineAsyncComponent(() => import("./DynamicComponent.vue")) : '')

const onClick = () => {
    isShow.value = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is solving issue for Vue 3 and mounting async components. This should be accepted as answer.

Comment: It's strange that this is not included in the official examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
import DynamicComponent from './DynamicComponent.vue'


export default {
    setup() {
        const state = reactive({
            name: computed(() => isShow ? DynamicComponent : '')
        });

        ...

        return {
            state,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with this seems to be to do with the way we register components when we use the `setup` script - see [the official docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html) for more info. I've found that you need to register the component globally in order to reference it by string in the template.

For example, for the below Vue component:

```js
<template>
  <component :is="item.type" :item="item"></component>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  // Where item.type contains the string 'MyComponent'
  const props = defineProps<{
    item: object
  }>()
</script>
```

We need to register the component in the main.ts, as such:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'

var app = createApp(App);
app.component('MyComponent', MyComponent)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: This seems to the best solution. As you can import your components using the defineAsyncComponent, and it works without hassle

Answer (score -1):

Using 'watch' everything works.

```
<template>
  <component :is="componentPath"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, ref, watch, SetupContext} from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    path: {type: String, required: true}
  },
  setup(props: { path: string }, context: SetupContext) {
    const componentPath = ref("");

    watch(
        () => props.path,
        newPath => {
          if (newPath !== "")
            import("@/" + newPath + ".vue").then(val => {
              componentPath.value = val.default;
              context.emit("loaded", true);
            });
          else {
            componentPath.value = "";
            context.emit("loaded", false);
          }
        }
    );

    return {componentPath};
  }
});
</script>
```