# Vue 3 dynamic component inside setup template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have following problem.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import defaultLayout from "@/layouts/default.vue";
import { useDefaultStore } from "@/stores/default";
let { getLayout } = useDefaultStore();
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="getLayout">
    <RouterView />
  </component>
</template>
```

I use Pinia as the store. I checked `getLayout` its getting `defaultLayout`

I know in Vue.js 2 you had to register it:

```
export default {
   components: {
      defaultLayout
   }
}
```

How do i do it now?

Comment: [I searched for vue 3 dynamic componenet](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why dynamic component is not working in vue3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500491/why-dynamic-component-is-not-working-in-vue3)

Answer (score 0):

You can't descructure the store like that, you have to use Pinias `storeToRefs()` (https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#using-the-store). Maybe it has something to do with that, I can't tell without the code of the store.

I'd recommend using this plugin https://github.com/JohnCampionJr/vite-plugin-vue-layouts if you're using Vite and need layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Use [defineAsyncComponent](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html)

```
defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/layouts/default.vue"))
```

or register the component globally in your `main.js`:

```
app.component('defaultLayout', defaultLayout)
```